# Python - scraping a headline from a URL, but the URL comes from user input

Tags: python, input, screen-scraping, scrape

I have a Python code which returns the headline and first paragraph of a BBC news story, but currently I have to supply the link. Here's the code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-40660355')

if (response.status_code == 200):

    pagehtml = html.fromstring(response.text)

    news1 = pagehtml.xpath('//h1[@class="story-body__h1"]/text()')
    news2 = pagehtml.xpath('//p[@class="story-body__introduction"]/text()')
print("\n".join(news1) + " (BBC News)")
print("\n".join(news2))
```

But this code relies on me coping the URL into the requests.get('') bit.

Here's my attempt at changing it to allow for user input:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

response = input()

if (response.status_code == 200):

    pagehtml = html.fromstring(response.text)

    news1 = pagehtml.xpath('//h1[@class="story-body__h1"]/text()')
    news2 = pagehtml.xpath('//p[@class="story-body__introduction"]/text()')
print("\n".join(news1) + " (BBC News)")
print("\n".join(news2))
```

But unfortunately, that has returned the following error:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-40825668
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript2.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-40825668
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to get this code to work by taking an input, rather than relying on the user changing the code to get the information from the URL.

Thanks

Comment: You want `raw_input` unless you are using python3.

Comment: Also, I'd say you want something along the lines of:
`response = requests.get(input())`

Comment: Hi @jordanm, I'm using Python 3.5 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = raw_input('Enter a URL: ')
response = requests.get(url)

if (response.status_code == 200):
    pagehtml = html.fromstring(response.text)

    news1 = pagehtml.xpath('//h1[@class="story-body__h1"]/text()')
    news2 = pagehtml.xpath('//p[@class="story-body__introduction"]/text()')
print("\n".join(news1) + " (BBC News)")
print("\n".join(news2))
```

To put the results in a .txt file, use the following:

```
with open('fileName.txt', 'a') as output:
    output.write(news1 + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you Anoop - in playing about with it, I landed with almost exactly what you had too - I hadn't thought to put the string before so I'm grateful. I've upvoted you, but because my rep is less than 15 apparently it's not counted!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's common practice to 'answer your own question', but I worked it out. I used raw_input instead, and replaced my input() but with:

```
my_url = raw_input()
response = requests.get(my_url)
```

Not sure if anyone else will see this, but hope that it helped!